# Cosmological energy density invariant under volumic transformations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, cosmology, field-theory, coordinate-systems

The cosmological energy density $\rho$ entering the definition of the energy-momentum tensor  is a scalar by definition, so even a coordinate transformation acting on spatial coordinates modifying the spatial volume should not change this density! Is that really true? I ask because in table 5  page 24 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.09787  people use for instance a purely spatial change of coordinates from Eulerian to Lagrangian that seems able to produce the vanishing of an over-density while under any transformation of spatial coordinates only from $x$ to $q$
i expect $\rho_x(x ,t)=\rho_q(q,t)=\rho(t) \Rightarrow$ if homogeneous in $q$ then also in $x$ coordinates. So it appears that the authors are not treating $\rho$ as a scalar!

Comment: Volume is a scalar, should volume therefore be invariant when changing volume?

Comment: sorry i don't understand how this is linked to my question: first Volume is not invariant : neither d³x nor d⁴x is invariant under general coordinate transformations. On the other hand sqrt(-det(g))d⁴x is invariant

Comment: Actually my feeling is that the transformation from Euler to Lagrange (that mimics evolution) does not belong to what we call general coordinate transformations: looks like something beyond ...and i would like a confirmation